# disable tint on custom uibarbuttonitem images

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, uibarbuttonitem

i have some custom bar button items in my navigation controller.

[image]

([maximize the image to see the borders better](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vswCz.png))

the above screenshot is how it should look like and how i added the barbutton item image.
as you can see, the icon has some darker gradients on top.

but since all icons get tinted, this dark gradient gets also tinted white and my icon looks extremely blurry.

i just dropped them into my storyboard.

[image]

is there a way to disable tinting this barbuttonitems?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In iOS 7, a navigation bar’s `tintColor` affects the color of the back indicator image, button titles, and button images. The `barTintColor` property affects the color of the bar itself. So, you can try setting the `barTintColor` and check if it solves your issue.

Also, when using the barButtonItem images, the following code is worth a try:

```
myImage = [myImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
```

Comment: i want the bar to have a white tint color, because the back button title and the title itself should be white.

Comment: The problem with this, is that disabled button looks like enabled button...

Comment: Thanks for Idea, I was facing same issue. TintColor was effecting UIBarButton color, So I changed the "Render As" property to "Original" in Attribute Inspector of Assets

Answer (score 17):

Adding to Anindya Answer:

In Xcode 9.2,

You can change the `"Render As"` property to `"Original"` in Attribute Inspector of Assets. This will prevent `NavigationBar.TintColor` to take effect on that Image if you used it in `UIBarButtonItem`

Comment: This works if you're using an asset catalog—awesome!

Comment: I wish it worked in Xcode 10.  There is no "Render As" in the attribute inspector on Xcode 10.