# An UIBarButtonItem is colored with tint color. Can I get this displayed as it is?

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem, tintcolor

The image below is the original one I want to display:

[image]

And I also put the following statement.

```
leftBtn.image = UIImage(named: "logo")
```

However, the image is displayes like the following one. I set the tint color as that dark grey.

[image]

Referencing this website [disable tint on custom uibarbuttonitem images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22482821/disable-tint-on-custom-uibarbuttonitem-images), I put this statement but it didn't make any change.

```
leftBtn.image?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)
```

Is there any other way to make the image shown as I want? Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this

```
leftBtn.image = UIImage(named: "logo").imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)
```

Answer (score 1):

That statement doesn't do anything. It returns the image but doesn't use it anywhere. You need to call the `setImage` method on your `leftBtn` to actually set the image.

Comment: Do you mean `.setBackgroundImage()` method? `UIBarButtonItem` doesn't have such method.

Comment: What I mean is whatever method you are already using to set the image, you need to use that to set an image that has already been set to be `AlwaysOriginal`.